# Embedding jolokia in a war

Tags: java, jolokia

I see the documentation on running jolokia as a separate war, running it as a agent, but how do I run it in my own war??

I have jetty running a single war, and want to embed it.

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's provided out of the box: https://jolokia.org/reference/html/agents.html#agent-war-programmatic

Please let me know, whether there are issues an I can help you here.

Comment: We have moved away from wars at this point anyways :P  THANKS!!